# Tab key not working in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tab-key

After an upgrade to `VS2010` from `VS2008` for `C#` and `Fortran` development I have noticed some peculiar behavior. While editing source files (`.cs`, `.for`, `.f90`) my tab key does not insert a tab character, it won't indent code and it won't code complete. I tried it with `VS2008` and everything works fine. Note that shift-Tab works ok to un-indent.

I tried `devenv /safemode` and I did fix things.

If anyone has seen this before please give me a hint as how to fix this issue.

OS is `win7-64 SP1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to brute-force fix the issue by going into Options/Environment/Keyboard and bind the [Tab] key with the `Edit.InsertTab` command for the Text Editor feature. See screenshot below:

[image: Keyboard Options]

That seems to have fixed my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I am seeing this problem as well. The following option seems to be the one that triggers the behavior:

```
Text Editor | C/C++ | Formatting | Automatic Indentation On Tab
```

If the above setting is `True`, the tab key will 'fix' the entire line so that it's indented according to how the IDE believes it should be indented (no matter where the cursor is on the line).

Changing the setting to `False` makes the tab key work as I expect it to.  I don't know how this setting got set to `True` on my machine.

VS 2012 also has this setting, and it works the same way.

Comment: I also saw this behavior today for the first time, after I installed "Update for Visual Studio 2013 Update 1". It was set to true out of nowhere.

Comment: I had this as well, completely out of the blue.

Comment: Same problem and solution in VS2013.  But never saw it in VS2010.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, try pressing <kbd>Alt-009</kbd> (press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> on a numeric keypad, then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>). That should generate a tab character. (The "alt-numbers" function doesn't work using the numbers across the top of the keyboard - you must use a keypad.)

You might need to submit a bug report to Microsoft.